# Maple cannot calculate the series expansion of "x^a*(1+x^b+exp(x))" at x=0

Tags: series, maple

Suppose we want to obtain the series expansion of `x^a*(1+x^b+exp(x))` at `x=0`. (This is just a simple example of many series expansion issues in Maple.) This can be done in **Mathematica** by

```
Series[x^a (1 + x^b + Exp[x]), {x, 0, 2}]
```

The output is `x^a (x^b+(2+x+x^2/2+O[x]^3))`.

However, in **Maple**, we will get an error.

```
series(x^a*(1+x^b+exp(x)), x = 0, 1);
```

If we do not use the `MultiSeries` package, the output is `Error, (in series/exp) unable to compute series`. If we use the `MultiSeries` package, the output is `Error, (in MultiSeries:-multiseries) unable to sort exponents, {0, b}`.

Is there a way to make Maple work for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a hint from that error message you showed, how about,

```
MultiSeries:-series(x^a*(1+x^b+exp(x)), x = 0, 3) assuming b>2;

          a    (1 + a)   1  (2 + a)    / (b + a)\
       2 x  + x        + - x        + O\x       /
                         2                       

MultiSeries:-series(x^a*(1+x^b+exp(x)), x = 0, 4) assuming b>3;

      a    (1 + a)   1  (2 + a)   1  (3 + a)    / (b + a)\
   2 x  + x        + - x        + - x        + O\x       /
                     2            6
```